# Relation between Nonparametric Statistics and Statistical Learning Theory

Tags: machine-learning, nonparametric

I used to hear some Statistics professor complaining about Machine Learning theories: "It is just Non-parametric Statistics". And, when I read Vapnik's book "Statistical Learning Theory", it seems he has been influenced a lot by non-parametric statistics. So, would anybody explain the similarity and difference between the two? My current guess (I am not familiar with the classic Nonparametric Statistics) is that Statistical Learning Theory cares much more about generalisation/prediction than Non-parametric Statistics?

Comment: I am answering this as a comment because I have been outside AI for most of this century, but I do pay some attention to important developments.  Its important to distinguish between parameter free and distribution free methods and AI.  Parameter free methods focus on a feature of the data, such as the median, and performs inference on it, such as the sign test.  On the other hand, distribution free methods assume parameters, but not the associated behavior.   For example,   Theil's regression with y=mx+b+e has m and b but makes no assumptions at all about e (continued)

Comment: So Theil's method of polynomial regression,  in this case first degree, says nothing at all about the statistical behavior of the sytem.  AI, of course, often focuses on features or training models, both with undefined system rules.  Bayesian nonparametric methods tend to focus on unknown model form.  They are not intrinsically the same thing as AI, but under suitable circumstances they will produce highly similar results.